# Codeacademy.com Something of Interest

Tags: python

I believe I set-up the program right, but it errors out on line 10. However, when I run that section by itself in Powershell it doesn't error out. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
def hotel_cost(nights):
    return nights * 140

bill = hotel_cost(5)

balance = int(raw_input("What's the balance?"))

rate = float(raw_input("What's the interest rate? i.e. .02 = 2%")

def get_min(balance,rate):
    return balance*rate
#line 10 is above
print get_min(balance,rate)

def add_monthly_interest(balance):
    return balance*((rate/12)+1)
```

What I'm trying to do is write a function with add_monthly_interest that will return a balance on a credit card with the interest added on it to it. So for example 100* ((.15/12)+1) =101.25

Comment: Codeacademy.com has its own forums for discussing specific questions. Did you check there first? I bet someone else has had a similar problem before.

Comment: It is likely "erroring out" on line 10 because you are missing a `)` on line 8: `rate = float(raw_input(...)`. The traceback says line 10 because the interpreter scans past line 8 looking for a closing paren, but hits the `def get_min` statement.

Comment: **Posting the actual error message** would go a long way to helping us help you :)

Comment: Your comment/label is misleading. `def get_min(balance,rate):` is line 10.

Answer (score 4):

```
rate = float(raw_input("What's the interest rate? i.e. .02 = 2%")
                                                                 ^
```

is missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: Yep yep... I knew in JS I would always look a couple of lines above the line that the error refers to. Good to know my habits will pay off through other languages :)

Comment: Thanks for the help...I can't believe it but it was actually, the close parentheses.

Codeacademy's forum are not as organize and efficient as stackoverflow.com